# Query called in typescript/javascript returns syntax error at "timestamp $3", same query in PSQL runs without a problem

Tags: postgresql, node-postgres

When I do the following query, everything completes fine in psql:

```
-- psql
INSERT INTO public.contest (contest_id, period_id, start_ts, end_ts, contest_name, default_format, status ) 
VALUES ('VKVPA', '2019/01', timestamp '2019-01-20 08:00', 
timestamp '2019-01-20 11:00', 'description', 'EDI', 'NEW' ) RETURNING contest_key;

-- console output:
contest_key |
------------+
         17 |
```

(`start_ts` and `end_ts` have type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`)
When I do the same in a program, it ends with syntax error:

```
// contest-debug.ts
import { Pool } from 'pg' ;

let pool = new Pool( {user: 'contest_owner', database: 'contest'} );

pool.query(
    "INSERT INTO public.contest (contest_id, period_id, start_ts, end_ts, contest_name, default_format, status ) "
    + "VALUES ($1, $2, timestamp $3, timestamp $4, $5, $6, 'NEW' ) RETURNING contest_key", 
    ['VKVPA', '2019/02',  '2019-01-20 08:00', '2019-01-20 11:00', 'VKV Provozni aktiv 2019/01', 'EDI']
  )
  .then( result => { 
      console.log(`New contest has number ${result.rows[0].contest_key}`);
    })
  .catch( reason => { console.log( 'Contest creation failed:', reason )});
```

Console output:

```
Contest creation failed: { error: syntax error at or near "$3"
    at Connection.parseE (D:\dev\cav\log2any\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:601:11)
    at Connection.parseMessage (D:\dev\cav\log2any\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:398:19)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\dev\cav\log2any\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:120:22)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:193:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:296:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:277:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:232:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:150:17)
  name: 'error',
  length: 92,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '42601',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: '135',
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'scan.l',
  line: '1134',
  routine: 'scanner_yyerror' }
```

When I try stepping through functions in pg module, I can see the same correct values all through, so why does the same thing cause SQL syntax error in javascript if the SQL itself is fine?

Unfortunately I do not know where to look for the final SQL text that the pg module creates.

What puzzles me even more is that yesterday the same program worked, today it does not. I did not make any changes to the program itself, tsc transpiler or pg modules.

**UPDATE**

The following code works. I did not pass the timestamp strings as parameters
and instead included them directly in the text of the query. Apparently, this is a bug either in libpq or in the javascript module.

```
pool.query(
    "INSERT INTO public.contest (contest_id, period_id, start_ts, end_ts, contest_name, default_format, status ) "
    + "VALUES ($1, $2, timestamp '2019-02-17 08:00', timestamp '2019-02-17 11:00', $3, $4, 'NEW' ) RETURNING contest_key", 
    ['VKVPA', '2019/02',  'VKV Provozni aktiv 2019/02', 'EDI']
  )
...
```

Comment: Assuming postgres is throwing the exception, check the postgres log file (in pg_log in the data folder) to see what the actual generated statement was.

Comment: I am afraid the log contains nothing useful. It does not show the final text, or even the values submitted:
`2019-04-09 10:44:41.532 CEST [3096] ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$3" at character 135
2019-04-09 10:44:41.532 CEST [3096] STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO public.contest (contest_id, period_id, start_ts, end_ts, contest_name, default_format, status ) VALUES ($1, $2, timestamp $3, timestamp $4, $5, $6, 'NEW' ) RETURNING contest_key`

Comment: The cause of the problem is slightly ambiguous documentation (SQL syntax: section 4.1.2.7 string constants) and failure to mention this specific feature in chapters 8.5 and 9.9. This kind of type casting cannot be used in this situation, a different syntax must be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this is a bug in postgres documentation. This syntax cannot be used in expressions to be assigned to columns, even when the string is a literal constant, but this is not explicitly mentioned in the manual (instead, it mentions that other type cast expressions can also be used for runtime conversions). I would recommend authors of the PostgreSQL manual to be a little bit more explicit in this detail.
Solution: use CAST( $3 AS TIMESTAMP ) or postgresql-specific syntax $3::timestamp.

```
pool.query(
    "INSERT INTO public.contest (contest_id, period_id, start_ts, end_ts, contest_name, default_format, status ) "
    + "VALUES ($1, $2, CAST ($3 AS TIMESTAMP), CAST($4 AS TIMESTAMP), $5, $6, 'NEW' ) RETURNING contest_key", 
    ['VKVPA', '2019/02',  '2019-01-20 08:00', '2019-01-20 11:00', 'VKV Provozni aktiv 2019/01', 'EDI']
  )
  .then( result => { 
      console.log(`New contest has number ${result.rows[0].contest_key}`);
    })
  .catch( reason => { console.log( 'Contest creation failed:', reason )});
```